# Ordered List and text content: How to Left center the numbers in large font size against small text on the right in css

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I need help with aligning the numbers so they appear in large font on the left, but centered against the description text on the right. I also need the dot removed after each number too. Can someone help to fix it please?

My code is below, and the end result should look like the image from this link [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWSpr.png)

```css
  .navh  {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        position: relative;
        background: #1b9fa4;
        border-radius: 2%;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 120px;
        background-color: #1b9fa4;
        border-color: #1b9fa4;
    }
    
    #item1 :after {
           border-left: 0px solid; 
      }
    
      .navh  :after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-left: 62.5px solid white;
      border-top: 62.5px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 62.5px solid transparent;
      z-index:1;
    
    }
    .navh  :before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        right: -103px;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 106px solid #1b9fa4;
        border-top: 150px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 150px solid transparent;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    
    .navh li{
       /* border: solid red;*/
        font-size: 1.7em;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 3%;
    }
    
    
    .navh span{
      font-size: small;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="navh"id="item1">
     <ol>
     <li><span>Some text here, Some text here, Some text here, Some text here, Some text here, Some text here...</span></li>
     <li><span>Some text here, Some text here, Some text here, Some text here, Some text here, Some text here...</span></li>
     <li><span>Some text here, Some text here, Some text here, Some text here</span></li>
    </ol>
     </div>
```

Comment: The link below may help you... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66718560/ordered-list-and-text-content-how-to-left-center-the-numbers-in-large-font-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update code which I mentioned below, there some issue in your code so I rectify it also, please refer code below mentioned

**HTML**

```
<div class="navh"id="item1">
<ol>
 <li><span>Some text here, Some text here, Some text here, Some text here, Some text here, Some text here...</span></li>
 <li><span>Some text here, Some text here, Some text here, Some text here, Some text here, Some text here...</span></li>
 <li><span>Some text here, Some text here, Some text here, Some text here</span></li>
</ol>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navh  {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
position: relative;
background: #1b9fa4;
border-radius: 2%;
float: left;
margin-left: 120px;
background-color: #1b9fa4;
border-color: #1b9fa4;
counter-reset: section;
}
#item1 :after {
   border-left: 0px solid; 
}
.navh > ol:after {
 content: "";


position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 62.5px solid white;
  border-top: 62.5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 62.5px solid transparent;
  z-index:1;

}
.navh > ol:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -103px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 106px solid #1b9fa4;
    border-top: 150px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 150px solid transparent;
    z-index: 2;
}

.navh li{
   /* border: solid red;*/
    font-size: 1.7em;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 3%;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.navh ol > li:before{
  counter-increment: section;
  content: " " counter(section) "";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}

.navh span{
  font-size: small;
}
.navh ol{
  list-style:none;
  padding-left:15px
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help!